# Issue on child theme installation

Tags: wordpress, themes

I've tried to install either the Fusion or Thematic child themes for my blog.  My Wordpress directory is located at `http://myblog.com/wordpress` while my domain is just `http://myblog.com` (example).

Everything works fine with both basic themes or the parent Fusion or Thematic themes. When I install a child theme for either framework, I can view the preview and can click <kbd>Activate</kbd>.

However, after that my entire site crashes, I can't even view the WordPress admin panel. I've had to restore my database from my hosting provider just to get my blog working. All that I'm able to see is my favicon icon and a blank page.

I've tried to deactivate all plugins and this doesn't help either.

I really want to use the Hybrid News child template.  Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the child theme you are using has some problems. Usually site or browser crashes because of some script that consumes a lot of memory like infinite loop. 
There should not be any problem with the wordpress or thematic framework as I have used them before a lot and didnt face a single issue.